# Why is it faster to compact a portion of the managed heap than the entire heap?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I was reading [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t.aspx) on MSDN. In the first paragraph under
 the "Generations and Performance" subheading is written:

> First, it is faster to compact the memory for a portion of the managed
>   heap than for the entire managed heap.

But *why* ?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Without digging into the article, I believe this can be answered with the same answer to "why is it faster to eat a piece of pie than the entire pie"?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? It sounds like you are asking why doing less work is less work than doing more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article does not go into any detail to back up that claim, however, there is a simple explanation.

If A is a portion of the heap and B is the entire heap, then clearly compacting A is *less work* than compacting B because it is smaller. There are fewer chunks of memory to track, fewer memory copies being performed, and fewer pointers to update (the simplified description of references in memory-managed languages are actually double pointers, and they need to be updated during trash compaction).